# Use one background resource image for all devices to conserve space?

Tags: android

On an `hdpi` device when the single background resource is in the `ldpi` folder it is not rendered. However when it is placed in the `xxxhdpi` folder it is rendered on an hdpi device.

• So will the `xxxhdpi` folder scale down across all other devices efficiently?

• When placed in the `ldpi` folder, the image won't render due to **OOM** issues?

People suggest that the resources be placed in a single drawable folder however almost all devices render the image resources slowly when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

usually the folder ldpi is avoided by programmers, regarding its leak of usage in the app.
the difference between hdpi,mdpi,xhpdi,xxhpdi is the image size, and to fit every console without affecting its efficiency. if your images have different measures that fit each folder then put them in there, but if they have the same measures no use of putting the same image in all folders, it will just take space.

there is a mdpi, xhpdi, xxhdpi folders to avoid the affects that may occur on a cetain image which is located in only the hdpi folder. (of course each folder must have certain measures)

Comment: So if the resources are the same size and contained only in the xxxhdpi folder they will scale down across all devices automatically?

Comment: if there is no difference between the images in that folder and the other folders it wont do any difference